# Codeigniter upgrade issues

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I recently upgraded my version of codeigniter from 2.2.0 to version 3.0.0 and I am experiencing some issues. I have a piece of code in config/constants.php which fetches configuration data from the database and sets the values to the constants. The code is as below:

```
require_once ( BASEPATH. 'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get_where ('settings_table', array('id' => '1'));
$row = $query->row_array();
define ("LOGO",$row["logo"]);
```

This code was working well until I upgraded codeigniter and now i get this error: **Notice: Use of undefined constant  'EXT' in file-path/config/constants.php**.

What could be the reason for it and how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In CI 3.0 the EXT constant is not defined in the index.php

CI 2.2.2 example

```
// The PHP file extension
// this global constant is deprecated.
define('EXT', '.php');
```

To get this to work with your script just change it to:

```
require_once ( BASEPATH. 'database/DB.php'); 
//or whatever the extension is for that file
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I have made that change and got the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function log_message() in file-path/system/database/DB_driver.php on line 375

Comment: Have you updated all the files in the system directory with the new ones from the 3.0 update?

Comment: The log_message function should be autoloaded. Can you check that you can find the function in the system directory? It should be in System/Core/Common.php

Comment: I think i might know the problem, try access the DB object like this.
`$CI =& get_instance(); $db = $CI->db;`

Comment: Yes,  the function is present in the file

Comment: The second solution displays the following error...  Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in system/core/Codeigniter.php

Comment: Im not 100% sure but maybe they have changed something that is preventing it from running this in the new version. It might be worth creating a custom config file (say: contants2.php or whatever), moving your custom code in that and loading this using the autoloader. This should load after the core has been initialised. Other than this I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: I have tried that but for some reason my apache shuts down whenever I run the page. Thanks for your input but in case you figure something out I'll really appreciate